# More efficient javascript boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean, performance

I have a checkbox and some `<div>`s that show/hides whenever a checkbox is checked. Now it all works great but it could be more efficient.

```
jQuery("#filtertype").change(function () {
    if (jQuery("#posttype").is(":checked")) {
        jQuery("#postblock").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        jQuery("#postblock").slideUp("slow");
    }

    if (jQuery("#taxonomycat").is(":checked")) {
        jQuery("#taxonomyblock").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        jQuery("#taxonomyblock").slideUp("slow");
    }

    if (jQuery("#taxonomytag").is(":checked")) {
        jQuery("#taxonomyblocktag").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        jQuery("#taxonomyblocktag").slideUp("slow");
    }

    if (jQuery("#fieldjeskey").is(":checked")) {
        jQuery("#fieldblock").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        jQuery("#fieldblock").slideUp("slow");
    }

    if (jQuery("#sliderme").is(":checked")) {
        jQuery("#sliderblock").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        jQuery("#sliderblock").slideUp("slow");
    }
});
```

This works like it should; it gets the *ID* of the checkbox `<input>` and for every `<input>` (*#filtertype, #taxonomycat* etc.) it will show or hide a `<div>` (*#postblock, #taxonomyblock* etc.)

It may be smarter to get the *ID* of every `<input>` and toggle the `slideUp`, `slideDown` function.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, rather than have a list of `id` selectors, put a single class of each of those checkboxes, along with a `data` attribute to specify the relation. Something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="posttype" class="filter-checkbox" data-rel="postblock" value="foobar" />
```

Then in javascript you can simplify all the code above to the following:

```
jQuery("#filtertype").change(function() {
    $('.filter-checkbox').each(function() {
        var func = this.checked ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp';
        $('#' + $(this).data('rel'))[func]('slow');
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BEkes/)

Comment: Actually it's not yet exactly what I want.. Say I have 3 checkboxes. The ones that are checked must shown a div. The not selected ones not. How to get this?

Comment: It's acting a bit strange: As I check the first checkbox the first time, the foobar will come up. When I uncheck it, nothing happens, only when I uncheck the other one it disappears.

Comment: @LarsKerff your fiddle seems to work fine, although your HTML has a lot of errors in it.

Comment: It's because there's some php in it indeed.

Comment: The PHP was fine - it was invalid because of improper attributes (`option`) random closing tags, and various other things. Either way, here's a fixed version using my example above: http://jsfiddle.net/BEkes/6/

Comment: Aah okay, yes indeed you're right.. Thanks for your patience and help.

Answer (score 4):

It could be more efficient by [not using jQuery](http://vanilla-js.com/).

Replace all of your `jQuery("#someID").is(":checked")` with
`document.getElementById('someID').checked`, and short of writing your own lightweight animation engine that's as good as you'll get.

Or you can go down the dark path of obscurity:

```
jQuery("#postblock")["slide"+(document.getElementById('posttype').checked ? "Down" : "Up")]("slow");
```

But that's probably not a good idea :p